# Is the lamp ON or IN the ceiling?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What preposition should I use when referring to the lamp **in / on** the ceiling?

[image]

Comment: This picture shows three different lights—the large one (chandelier style), the smaller round ones recessed into the ceiling, and the hidden "cove lighting" that's actually lit. Which are you referring to?

Comment: If there is a difference in the andwer then it'll be intersting to know about both chandelier and the smaller round ones recessed into the ceiling.

Comment: OK. I described both of those in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

That chandelier-style lamp is **on** the ceiling, or is **hanging from** the ceiling. Your picture also shows some recessed lights (see my picture below), which could be described as being **in** the ceiling.

[image]